# Minimal coredump needed to get backtraces for all threads with gdb

Tags: linux, gcc, gdb, coredump, backtrace

We want to pull stack traces from a running process. Pulling stack traces directly with gstack is not an option and using a gdbserver works, but is quite slow due to the network.
We were curious if we can pull a core dump of the process with

```
gdb --ex "attach $PID" --ex "gcore core_dump_file" --ex "q"
```

copy the core dump to a container with the compiled executable and then analyze the core dumps inside the container with

```
gdb $PATH_TO_EXECUTABLE core_dump_file --ex "thread apply all bt" --ex "q"
```

The core dump can reach sizes of hundreds of gigabytes in production, so we would like to filter the coredump as much as possible.

The memory sections written to the core dump can filtered by changing the `coredump_filter` file at `/proc/$PID/coredump_filter` (see the [man page for core](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/core.5.html)). As long as bit 0 (Dump anonymous private mappings) is set, everything works fine, we get the expected backtraces. It can be set with

```
echo 0x1 > "proc/$PID/coredump_filter
```

Unfortunately, the anonymous private mappings are very large and make up about 75% of the unfiltered coredump, e.g. in one of our test cases, the default coredump with `0x33` was 5 GB, and the filtered coredump with `0x1` was still 3.8 GB large.

If we filter as much as possible by setting all bits to zero with

```
echo 0x0 > "proc/$PID/coredump_filter
```

the resulting coredump becomes very small with a size of only one MB (down from several gigabytes of size), however using `thread apply all bt` fails with

```
Thread 1 (LWP 2653):
#0  0x00007fae7d4218fd in ?? ()
Backtrace stopped: Cannot access memory at address 0x7ffe21387490
```

With the fully filtered coredump, I can see that the gdb does not know which shared libraries to load:

```
(gdb) info shared
No shared libraries loaded at this time.
```

What does gdb actually need to get the backtraces? Is there a way to filter everything gdb does not need for the back traces? Is there a better way to get the backtraces (does not necessarily have to use gdb)?

Comment: What you really want to do? Typically a stack trace is only needed if you debug a broken program which means nothing you need from minute to minute. So why you want to do so mcuh stuff around core dumps if you need it very rarely. XY problem?

Answer (score 0):

> What does gdb actually need to get the backtraces?

1. The stacks of all threads (obviously)
2. Enough of the heap to recover the `_DYNAMIC[].r_debug->r_map` and the entire link chain of `struct link_map`s to know where all the DSOs are.

> Is there a way to filter everything gdb does not need for the back traces?

Not with a `coredump_filter`, there isn't.

> Is there a better way to get the backtraces (does not necessarily have to use gdb)?

There are some ways:

1. You could install a signal handler (for something like `SIGPWR` or another rarely used signal) into each thread. In the signal handler you could walk the stack (using e.g. libunwind), and `write` that stack somewhere.
   It's then a small matter of arranging to send the signal to every thread.
2. You could use something like Google [user-space core dumper](https://code.google.com/archive/p/google-coredumper/), which gives you complete control of which parts of the process are saved into the `core`, and which are filtered out.
   It also allows you to compress the `core`
3. You may try to use LLDB instead of GDB.

Unfortunately, option (1) requires quite a bit of very fiddly async-signal-safe code, and mistakes may cause your process to crash or deadlock.

Option (2) doesn't have that problem, but the last public release was 15 years ago, and may no longer work.

Option (3) may or may not be faster than GDB, but from what I understand LLDB may be a lot less "chatty" than GDB/gdbserver, and that may help with the speed when the network latency is significant.